# How to turn a query result into a js variable (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, require

I've been searching for this for a day now and I'm basically hopeless. 
All I want to do is export the query result as a string (so dataString basically) so I can import as a string in my external .js file.

```
module.exports.getKlanten = function(req, res){
console.log("zoekt naar klanten");
pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
    if(err){
        return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
    }
    client.query("select * from abc.relations limit 5", function(err,result){
        done();
        if(err){
            return console.error('error running query', err);
        }            
        var dataString = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
        var count = Object.keys(result.rows).length;

        var klanten = result.rows;

        res
        .status(200)            
        .render("index", {dataString: dataString, klant: klanten, count: count});        

    console.log("done");
    })        
});
```

}

And what would I have to do in the js file to import the string then? It looks so easy yet I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this

```
module.exports.getKlanten = function(req, res){
console.log("zoekt naar klanten");
return "Hello world"; }
```

and then in your external .js file, you can import it like this

```
const myModule = require('./JSFile');
```

and use it like this

```
console.log(myModule.getKlanten());
```

Also, use a return statement so that you have a string in your variable.

Comment: Thanks Hassan, but I already tried and when I try to return the dataString it's not valid. Probably because it's 'stuck' in the query request and can't be used outside of that. Any solution to that?

Comment: @reitnellop Just make a variable before the pool.connect and then assign this variable to the dataString once you have the results.  This way its scope will be function wide.

Comment: I did, but also no result :(.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you need to use the same function externally somewhere else and also for http handler so split it into three files.

```js
//getKlanten.js
module.exports.getKlanten = function(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pool.connect(function(err, client, done){//make sure pool is avialble here
            if(err){
             console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
             reject(err);
            }
            client.query("select * from abc.relations limit 5", function(err,result){
                if(err){
                    console.error('error running query', err);
                    reject(error);
                }            
                var dataString = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
                var count = Object.keys(result.rows).length;
                var klanten = result.rows;
        
                var data = {dataString: dataString, klant: klanten, count: count}      
                resolve(data);
            })        
        });
    })
}

//in external.JS
var getKlanten = require('getKlanten');
getKlanten().then(function(object) {
    console.log(object);
}, function(err){
    console.log(err);
})

//in http handler file

var getKlanten = require('getKlanten');

module.exports = function(req,res) {
    getKlanten().then(function(data) {
        res
        .status(200)            
        .render("index", data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But all I need is the string dataString :/

Comment: Then just repalce resolve(data)with resolve (datastring)